# Идентификация машины юзера

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли с помощью JS определить устройство юзера? Не важно какими именно данными придется оперировать, главное, чтобы можно было отличить одного пользователя от другого.

Comment: так что нужно: определить операционную систему пользователя (или его браузер) или получить его уникальный идентификатор (типа mac-адреса)? первое просто.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой способ - записать случайное значение в localStorage. Но если у вас есть сервер - то еще проще для этой цели использовать куки.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку!

Answer (score 0):

Можно определить агента пользователя в глобальном объекте `navigator.userAgent` и уже потмо можно узнать и по агенту узнавать устройство.

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    // Пользователь сидит с мобильного приложения или таблетки
}
```